# Simplest method to merge two objects using a Lens

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ramda.js

I'm new to Ramda and trying to restrict myself to not resorting to vanilla JS methods for tasks like this while I adjust. I'm stuck on something that feels very simple. Ramda loses clarity for me as soon as I need to chain some things together like this.

I used [`R.groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) to aggregate some other data into an object with some keys, I have a target object I'd like to merge this with - however the keys from the groupby are nested within it.

I can create a [view](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view) with a lens on the target property to see the data transformed to match - I'm not quite sure how to do the reverse to apply the grouped data to the nested object.

```js
let ungroupedData = [
  {"tag":"foo","id":99}, {"tag":"bar","id":33}, {"tag":"foo","id":14}, {"tag":"bar","id":26},
  {"tag":"baz","id":99}, {"tag":"qux","id":33}, {"tag":"foo","id":49}, {"tag":"bar","id":13}
];

let groupedData = R.map(R.pluck('id'), R.groupBy(R.prop('tag'),ungroupedData));

console.log({groupedData});
// groupedData:
// {
//   "foo": [99, 14, 49],
//   "bar": [33, 26, 13],
//   "baz": [99],
//   "qux": [33]
// }

let nestedTargetObjectToMerge = {
    "foo": { 
        //...
        "ids": [344, 121],
        //...
     },
     "bar": {
        //...
        "ids": [103, 66],
        //...
     }
}

// a view of the target object using a lens which matches groupedData
let view = R.map(R.view(R.lensProp("ids")), nestedTargetObjectToMerge);

console.log({view});
// view:
// {
//   "foo": [344, 121],
//   "bar": [103, 66]
// }

/* 
   let merged = ??
   // R.mergeDeepWithKey ?
   // R.over?
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

#### Intended result

```js
 {
     "foo" : {
       "ids" : [344, 121, 99, 14, 49],
     },
     "bar" : {
       "ids" : [103, 66, 33, 26, 13],
     },
     "baz" : { 
       "ids": [99],
     },
     "qux" : {
       "ids" : [33],
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you group, map the groups, and use `R.applySpec` with `R.pluck` to create an object with `ids`. Now you can use `R.mergeDeepWith` with `R.concat` combine the `ids` on both objects:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map, applySpec, pluck, mergeDeepWith, concat } = R;

const groupData = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('tag')),
  map(applySpec({
    ids: pluck('id')
  }))
)

const ungroupedData = [{"tag":"foo","id":99},{"tag":"bar","id":33},{"tag":"foo","id":14},{"tag":"bar","id":26},{"tag":"baz","id":99},{"tag":"qux","id":33},{"tag":"foo","id":49},{"tag":"bar","id":13}];
const nestedTargetObjectToMerge = {"foo":{"ids":[344,121]},"bar":{"ids":[103,66]}};

const groupedData = groupData(ungroupedData);

const result = mergeDeepWith(
  concat,
  nestedTargetObjectToMerge, 
  groupedData
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool! yep transforming the grouped object to fit the target is simplest.  cheers for the nod toward `applySpec`

Comment: I wonder though - what is the method for setting this data via a lens (without transforming the groupby object? does it exist?

Comment: The main problem I see with lenses is dynamic properties of the groups object. So I don't have any elegant solution that includes a lens.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was getting hung up on.

Comment: Yes, definitely better suited to `mergeDeepWith` than to `lenses`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to Ori Drori's, but enough different to include it as well:

```js
const extractIds = compose (map (objOf ('ids')), map (pluck ('id')), groupBy (prop ('tag')))

const group = compose (flip (mergeDeepWith (concat)), extractIds)

const nestedTargetObjectToMerge = {foo: {ids: [344, 121]}, bar: {ids: [103, 66]}}
const ungroupedData = [{tag: "foo", id: 99}, {tag: "bar", id: 33}, {tag: "foo", id: 14}, {tag: "bar", id: 26}, {tag: "baz", id: 99}, {tag: "qux", id: 33}, {tag: "foo", id: 49}, {tag: "bar", id: 13}]

console .log (
  group (ungroupedData) (nestedTargetObjectToMerge)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {compose, map, objOf, pluck, groupBy, prop, flip, mergeDeepWith, concat} = R </script>
```

Here `extractIds` converts your ungrouped data into the same format as your target object, and then `group` uses it to pass that into `mergeDeepWith (concat)`.  `extreactId` could easily be inlined into `group`, but I find it more readable like this.

---

However, I want to comment on this:

> I'm new to Ramda and trying to restrict myself to not resorting to vanilla JS methods for tasks like this while I adjust. I'm stuck on something that feels very simple. Ramda loses clarity for me as soon as I need to chain some things together like this.

I'm one of Ramda's founders and chief maintainers.  I'm a big fan.  But I would be very wary of this philosophy.  Ramda is a tool; it's meant to make it easier to work in a certain style.  But it's not supposed to take over everything for you.  It can often be used to make your code cleaner.  Use it when it does.  When it doesn't, don't try to squeeze it in.  If this is solely a learning exercise, then sure, play around with Ramda solutions.  But for your real work, don't try to force it.

And, while I'm pretty happy with the solution above -- and with Ori Drori's version -- I would not discount a plain JS solution using a single fold, like this:

```js
const group = (xs) => (target) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, {tag, id}) => ({
    ...a, 
    [tag]: {...(a [tag] ?? {}), ids: [... (a [tag] ?.ids ?? []), id]}
  }), target)


const nestedTargetObjectToMerge = {foo: {ids: [344, 121]}, bar: {ids: [103, 66]}}
const ungroupedData = [{tag: "foo", id: 99}, {tag: "bar", id: 33}, {tag: "foo", id: 14}, {tag: "bar", id: 26}, {tag: "baz", id: 99}, {tag: "qux", id: 33}, {tag: "foo", id: 49}, {tag: "bar", id: 13}]

console .log (
  group (ungroupedData) (nestedTargetObjectToMerge)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: interesting - i appreciate the perspective. it’s a learning exercise, to exclude js. I like the legibility of Ramda. The spread syntax and nullish coalescing looks nice and compact, but feels a little less readable (to me) but i’m sure many folks feel the opposite :)

Comment: Yeah, this one is around the balance point for me.  But I watch some people go to ridiculous lengths to do something point-free, and like to nip that in the bud.  Ramda does some very nice things.  People making it into something it's not just confuse the issue.  Either Ori Drori or my Ramda versions seem clear and readable, just not *much* better than the vanilla one.